# Easiest way to convert string to list

Tags: python, string, list

Let there be a string list_string = '[1,2,3]'
the desired output would be the list inside the string, but not as a string bus as a list
list_list = [1,2,3]

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module might be what you are looking for.

```
import json

list_string = '[1,2,3]'
list_list = json.loads(list_string)

print(list_list)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(list_list[0])  # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `eval` if you are very sure the string can be converted into list and does not contain dangerous code:

```
>> eval('[1,2,3]') == [1, 2, 3]
# True
```

Comment: You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for a somewhat safer option.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to slice off the brackets and then use **[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)**:

```
>>> list_string = '[1,2,3]'
>>> list_list = list_string[1:-1].split(',')
>>> list_list
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list_list2 = [int(x) for x in list_string[1:-1].split(',')]
>>> list_list2
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list_list3 = list(map(int, list_string[1:-1].split(',')))
>>> list_list3
[1, 2, 3]
```